# Tkinter Dynamic Dictionary for Matrix- Cant use .get method on entry windows

Tags: python, loops, matrix, tkinter

I have been working on a program which can generate a matrix of a user-defined size, and can then perform operations on the matrix. The program is divided into a few parts.

First, the user enters the rows and columns, which, when submitted, will open a tkinter window with a matrix of entry boxes.

Each of these entry boxes is a value in a dynamic `entries` dictionary. The lists `gridrows` and `gridcols` are used to give coordinates for the `.grid` method for arranging the entry boxes.

The issue I am having is assigning a command to get the user input after typing their values into the matrix. I have tried creating a function `storevals` which will append all matrix entries to the `matrixinput` list.

When I run this program, I get the the matrix entry window, and after typing in the values into each box of the matrix, I get the same error message from line 50: `AttributeError:"NoneType" object has no attribute "get"`. It appears that the entry boxes have no type, which seems to be lost after the `.grid` arranging of the windows.

Is there any way to assign the user entries in these windows to a list? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *

#Take user input for matrix size and store in matrixrows and matrixcols variables as integers.
master = Tk()
master.title("Matrix Size")
Label(master, text = "Rows").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text = "Columns").grid(row=1)


def storevals():
    matrixrows.append(int(rows.get()))
    matrixcols.append(int(cols.get()))
    master.quit()

matrixrows = []
matrixcols = []


rows = Entry(master)
cols = Entry(master)

rows.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
cols.grid(row =1, column = 1)

Button(master, text= "Enter", command = storevals).grid(row=3, column =0, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()

norows = matrixrows[0]
nocols = matrixcols[0]
matrixlist =[]

for i in range(0,norows):
    matrixlist.append([])

for i in range(0,norows):
    for j in range(0,nocols):
        matrixlist[i].append(nocols*0)



#Generate a matrix entry window with entries correpsonding to the matrix

master2 = Tk()
master2.title("Enter Matrix Values")
matrixinput=[]

def storevals():
    for key in entries:
        matrixinput.append(entries[key].get())
        print(matrixinput)


Button(master2, text= "Submit Matrix", command = storevals).grid(row=norows+1, column =round(nocols/2), sticky=W, pady=4)

gridrows=[]
gridcols=[]


#creates two lists, gridcols and gridrows which are used to align the entry boxes in the tkinter window

for i in range(0,norows):
    for j in range(0,nocols):
        gridrows.append(i)

for i in range(0,norows):
    for j in range(0,nocols):
        gridcols.append(j)


entries ={}
for x in range(0,nocols*norows):
           entries["Entrybox{0}".format(x)]=Entry(master2).grid(row=gridrows[x], column=gridcols[x])

print(entries)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't looked at the content of entries, that you print just before mainloop()

```
entries ={}
for x in range(0,nocols*norows):
           entries["Entrybox{0}".format(x)]=Entry(master2).grid(row=gridrows[x], column=gridcols[x])

print(entries)
```

`grid()`, `pack()` and `place()` all return `None`.

If you want to keep the widget you need to assign it to a variable and then call `grid()`.

```
entries ={}
for x in range(0,nocols*norows):
    widget = Entry(master2)
    widget.grid(row=gridrows[x], column=gridcols[x])
    entries["Entrybox{0}".format(x)] = widget

print(entries)
```